# Supplement SQLAlchemy Results With Python Functions

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there any way to use python functions in a(n) SQLAlchemy `select()`?  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
select(Table.id, python_func(Table.type))
```

The expectation would be that the library issues a `SELECT id, type FROM table` statement to fetch the data.  When the data is being converted to Rows, it would call the python function with the `type` and use the result of that function for one of the column values.

```
[(1, 'output_for_1'), (2, 'output_for_2'), ...]
```

I considered using hybrid_property.  This would work fine for accessing the data for an object that is already loaded into memory, but fails when including the property in a SELECT clause.  The logic in python does not have a(n) SQL equivalent, so it errors trying to generate the SQL statement.  This approach might work if I could tell SQLAlchemy to just do nothing in the SQL, but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

```
    @hybrid_property
    def type_message(self) -> str:
        return get_lookup_detail('TYPE', self.type)

    @type_message.inplace.expression
    @classmethod
    def _type_message_exp(cls) -> ColumnElement:
        return ColumnElement()  # any way to return an "empty" clause so no SQL is rendered?
```

I tried setting the expression to `null().label('type_message')` so that the SQL would just select NULL, but then the type_message property is shown as None at runtime and the function call is not executed.

Comment: `select()` is used to generate a SQL statement. If you want to trigger a function in the statement, it can be a custom SQL function (not a Python function). You can always do the processing easily after you get the query result.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#working-with-sql-functions Not sure but maybe this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: @LouisHuang the logic I need to run does not have a SQL analog (without a bunch of custom procedure development that we are trying to steer away from).  I was hoping that I could take advantage of some library feature to enhance the results returned from the SQL (e.g., add python-calculated columns to the results).  However, it seems like I'm going to have to do manual processing to convert the SQL results to dicts/objects with the enhanced data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent more time on this and came up with two options.  The first one I did was to just perform post-processing on the SQL results.

```py
def _transformer(row: dict):
    row['type'] = get_lookup_detail('TYPE', row['type'])
    return row

results = [_transformer(row._asdict()) for row in session.execute(select(Table.id, Table.type)).all()]
```

This worked well enough for my needs, but I didn't really love the idea of adding an extra round of iteration through the results and needing to convert all of the rows to `dict`s. While I was in the SQLAlchemy documentation for other reasons, I came across [TypeDecorator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) and the [type_coerce()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.type_coerce) function.  This gave me another idea that is more like what I was originally looking for.

```py
class LookupDetail(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String
    cache_ok = True

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return get_lookup_detail('TYPE', value)

stmt = select(Table.id,
              type_coerce(Table.type, LookupDetail()))
session.execute(stmt).all()
```

My (very unscientific) testing suggests that the performance of these two approaches is very similar on small result sets (on the scale of dozens of rows).  Unfortunately, I don't have a good example to test a larger volume on right now.

At least for the smaller result sets that I tested, it seems that choosing between them is more of a personal preference.  The first option is maybe a little simpler code, but is not necessarily as easy to reuse.  You may need to create new transformer functions for every query.  There's also a risk that this does not scale well to large result sets.

The second option is maybe a little less intuitive at first glance, but it is taking advantage of core features of the SQLAlchemy library.  It doesn't require additional iterations since the function is called while the results are being processed by SQLAlchemy, so the risk of performance degradation while scaling is less.

One final difference between the two approaches is the ability to execute functions that require multiple columns.  For example, say you wanted to have a field that indicated if the person was above or below the average salary for their position.  To calculate this you probably need to call a function that needs the person's position and their salary.  With the first approach this is really easy since you have access to the whole row as a `dict` object.  For the second approach, you'd need to do something to combine the two columns in SQL, then parse out the separate values in `process_result_value()` before calling the function.